# Trying to put list data into another list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the program below I am using fee head id and trying to access dynamic data but when I select or click on any element of the first list it does not go to the next list.
After clicking on any element in first list, the element should disappear from first list and display in the second list. I am using a theme which has built-in classes in `JS` and `JSP`.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="leftBox">
                <select id="feesHeads" multiple="multiple" class="multiple nostyle form-control" style="height:300px;">
                <!--     <option value="1">Spain</option>
                    <option value="2">Germany</option>
                    <option value="3">Uruguay</option>
                    <option value="4" selected="selected">Brazil</option>
                    <option value="5" selected="selected">England</option>
                    <option value="6" selected="selected">Portugal</option>
                    <option value="7">Argentina</option>
                    <option value="8">Italy</option>
                    <option value="9">Croatia</option>
                    <option value="10">Denmark</option>
                    <option value="11">Russia</option>
                    <option value="12">Greece</option>
                    <option value="13">Chile</option>
                    <option value="14">Côte d'Ivoire</option>
                    <option value="15" selected="selected">France</option>
                    <option value="16">Sweden</option>
                    <option value="17">Switzerland</option>
                    <option value="18">Republic of Ireland</option>
                    <option value="19">Australia</option>
                </select> --> 
                <br/>
                <span id="box1Counter" class="count"></span>
                <div class="dn"><select id="box1Storage" name="box1Storage" class="nostyle"></select></div>
            </div>

            <div class="dualBtn">

                <button id="to2" type="button" class="btn" ><span class="icon12 minia-icon-arrow-right-3"></span></button>
                <button id="allTo2" type="button" class="btn" ><span class="icon12 iconic-icon-last"></span></button>
                <button id="to1" type="button" class="btn marginT5"><span class="icon12 minia-icon-arrow-left-3"></span></button>
                <button id="allTo1" type="button"class="btn marginT5" ><span class="icon12 iconic-icon-first"></span></button>

            </div>

            <div class="rightBox">

                <select id="box2View" multiple="multiple" class="multiple nostyle form-control" style="height:300px;"></select>
                <br/>
                <span id="box2Counter" class="count"></span>

                <div class="dn"><select id="box2Storage" class="nostyle"></select></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End .form-group  -->
</div>

</div><!-- End .panel -->

</div><!-- End .span6 -->

</div><!-- End .row -->
```

Comment: Please rewrite your title.

Comment: Please intend your code properly.

Comment: Let's make it simple, you have two select element. When you click on the first one's option it should disappear from there and moved to the second one. Is it??

Comment: Your commenting out is wrong. First fix that. You have commented out `options` including the closing `</select>` tag. You also have redundant closing `</div>`s at the end.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the firstList's option remove it from there and append it to the secondList. I've created a simple demo that might go with your scenario.

**HTML :**

```
First :
<select id="firstList">
    <option>Mango</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Apple</option>
</select>
<br />
Second
<select id="secondList"></select>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$("#firstList").on("change", function(){
    var selectedItem = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    $(this).children("option:selected").remove();
    $("#secondList").append($("<option> </option>").text(selectedItem));
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/unbbmLg7/)

**Note :** *It's just an overview of how you can implement it. But what you want is entirely upto you.*